# Memory location of a structure object in C

Tags: c

Here is the piece of code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct abc
{
    int a;
    void* b;
};

int main()
{
    void* tmp = malloc(100);
    struct abc* myobj = tmp;
    printf("sizeof myobj:%ld\n", sizeof(struct abc));
    printf("myobj:%p\n", myobj);

    myobj->b = myobj + sizeof(struct abc);
    printf("myobj->b:%p\n", myobj->b);

    myobj->b = (void*)myobj + sizeof(struct abc);
    printf("myobj->b:%p\n", myobj->b);
}
```

When I run this code, I get the following output

```
sizeof myobj:16
myobj:0x1610010
myobj->b:0x1610110
myobj->b:0x1610020
```

I am not able understand why location of myobj is 0x1610110 when I am adding 16 bytes to the myobj which starts at 0x1610010
However, when I typecast myobj to (void*) and add 16 bytes, I get the proper address of 0x1610020.

Can someone explain me this ?

thanks

Comment: myobj+1 adds as many bytes as required to point to the next object of type struct abc. So, myobj + sizeof(struct abc) is actually adding sizeof(struct abc)*sizeof(struct abc) bytes.

Comment: ...and this is called "pointer arithmetic". You're seeing the difference between pointer arithmetic on a `void *` pointer versus an `abc *` pointer.

Comment: @BenZotto: Pointer arithmetic on `void*` is invalid in standard C. gcc (unfortunately IMHO) provides a language extension that makes it act like arithmetic on `char*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pointer math! For each increment on a pointer, the address goes up by the size of the data in the pointer. This would do it:

```
myobj->b = myobj + 1;
```